# Haptic (vibration) feedback on Samsung Galaxy S8+

Tags: android, kotlin, samsung-galaxy, haptic-feedback

The goal is to receive vibration feedback during some action happened in app.
`HapticFeedbackConstants` has several constants which are responsible for different haptic types.
It is not documented well, but feels logically that `CONTEXT_CLICK` fits here. It is not available prior `M`, so the code is

```
fun View.performHapticFeedbackDefault() {
    performHapticFeedback(if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M) {
        HapticFeedbackConstants.CONTEXT_CLICK
    } else HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS)
}
```

That's working and confirmed on Nexus/Pixel phones, some Huawei etc, but isn't working for Samsung Galaxy phones and we should cover this segment

Seems that `Samsung` doesn't have such setting in vibration preferences also

How to perfom haptic feedback on Samsung devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found haptic type which available on Samsung and should be available on other devices - a keyboard haptic.

User is able to disable it from settings, but i think this is the type which covers most of the cases.

```
fun View.performHapticFeedbackDefault() {
    performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.KEYBOARD_TAP)
}
```

Comment: I'm also facing challenges with Samsung devices. And posted my question also. I'm trying to perform haptic feedback without user interaction. Link is here-https://stackoverflow.com/q/71390959/2404262 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Have you tried `KEYBOARD_TAP` haptic type? As i mentioned only few types work on samsung devices

Comment: Yeah `KEYBOARD_TAP` works in all devices.