# Android haptic feedback is not working in Samsung

Tags: android, haptic-feedback

I'm integrating haptic feedback in my android app which works fine in my Google Pixel 4a phone but its not working at all in Samsung devices. I'm using below snippet for calling it after getting a result from an API call:

```
activity?.window?.decorView?.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.CONFIRM, HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_GLOBAL_SETTING)
```

I have defined permission for `Vibrate` also in `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Please let me know if it's not possible without any click or touch listener.

Comment: please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/13152567/2219208

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh I have already mentioned that I'm calling it after getting a result from an API call not on `ClickListener` or `TouchListener`

Comment: have you added this to button android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"

Comment: I'm trying to `performHapticFeedback` on opening a new screen. So there is no user interaction.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? If not, I would suggest using `Vibrator` instead of `performHapticFeedback` since no touch is being performed. This answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17066803/5746918. According to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73987) haptic feedback is not enabled in Samsung devices by default and that will cause the device to not vibrate if you use `performHapticFeedback`. Have you tried this code after enabling touch interactions on said Samsung devices manually?

Comment: Yes @IshitaSinha I had to use vibration with different frequencies.

Comment: In that case, please post an answer and accept it so we all can benefit from your solution. :)

Comment: Yes @IshitaSinha. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find the solution with haptic feedback for Samsung devices so I went with the android's default vibration. Find below the snippet:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        (context.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(250, VibrationEffect.EFFECT_DOUBLE_CLICK))
    } else {
        (context.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator).vibrate(250)
    }
```